# C# code to download a website with images

Tags: c#, html, download

Given a URL, what would be the most efficient code to download the contents of that web page? I am only considering the HTML, the CSS and the Images.

Comment: Hello @janik313. Is there any specific issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");

    // Or you can get the file content without saving it
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
}
```

Comment: See [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0#remarks) about WebClient. Use HttpClient instead.